# Known version twisted python

Tags: python, pip, twisted

I would like to check what version of twisted python is installed on my OS. I need to have a version `17.1.0` or greater and I work on `CentOS 7`.

I tried this:

```
(.synapse)[root@nexus-chat1 .synapse]# twisted -v
  -bash: twisted : commande introuvable
```

But how can I upgrade my version? If I do this, will it update it?

```
(.synapse)[root@nexus-chat1 .synapse]# pip install twisted
```

Comment: Don't `pip install` anything as root.  Use OS packages and use virtualenv or another "sandbox"-type solution when OS packages aren't sufficient.  Using `pip` to install Python packages as root screws up your OS package manager and you'll regret it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
pip search twisted
```

among the output you should see the desired information:

```
Twisted (17.9.0)                     - An asynchronous networking framework written in Python
  INSTALLED: 16.3.0
  LATEST:    17.9.0
```

update to latest available version with:

```
pip install --upgrade twisted
```

Comment: pip to upgrade over-top of OS packages?  :(

Answer (score 0):

if you has installed twisted, you can write `pip show twisted`

```
(venv) ➜  testTwisted pip show twisted
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Name: Twisted
Version: 20.3.0
Summary: An asynchronous networking framework written in Python
Home-page: https://twistedmatrix.com/
Author: Twisted Matrix Laboratories
Author-email: twisted-python@twistedmatrix.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/ss/testTwisted/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: hyperlink, attrs, Automat, PyHamcrest, incremental, zope.interface, constantly
Required-by:
```